# connecting apache zeppelin to ignite on docker

Tags: docker, ignite, apache-zeppelin

Anyone managed to connect zeppelin to ignite in a docker setup?

looking for something like this:
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  ignite:
    image: apacheignite/ignite:1.9.0
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      - test

  zeppelin:
    image: apache/zeppelin:0.7.3
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    links:
      - ignite
    depends_on:
      - ignite
    networks:
      - test

networks:
  test:
```

I am setting the interperter address to ignite

```
ignite.addresses    ignite:47500..47509
```

and then in the notebook

```
%ignite.ignitesql
select _val, count(_val) as cnt from String group by _val order by cnt desc limit 10
```

getting this error

```
Failed to start Ignite node.
```

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ignite do you use?  
Zeppelin docs[1] says the only ignite-1.9 is supported by zeppelin-0.7.3  
  
[1] https://zeppelin.apache.org/supported_interpreters.html#ignite

Comment: Thanks , I changed to ignite 1.9.0 . same error...

Comment: Would you provide node config and any error details? e.g. stacktrace?

Comment: @Gadi Could you please check ignite interpreter log for any exceptions and share stack traces? A lot of reasons can cause such error message (different Ignite versions, connection problems due to a docker configuration, etc).

Comment: How do I enable these logs?

Comment: Logs should be enabled by default. Try to set proper IGNITE_HOME directory and check logs subdir. Seems, by default home dir is /tmp/ignite.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to go pass this error with the following link that talks about <ignite.jdbc.url> for ignite. Now I have another question about multiple caches. Seemed zeppelin is limited to one cache? https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.1/docs/data-analysis-with-apache-zeppelin

Comment: No, Ignite just need a valid cache name passed to run SQL queries due to architectural lack. Cross cache queries works well.

SQL query run method belongs to IgniteCache API as Ignite has no SQL API. So, some dummy cache instance is required to run a query.